# Multiple values in Database separated by comma show these values one by one in Dropdown list using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i have a shopping store many products which have multiple color values or some products have multiple size values like. **small,medium,large,XL**

i'm store like these values in database column and want to show one by one in dropdown select list. i using codeigniter for this but nothing show in dropdown list. Here is my code.

**Model**

```
public function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_products')
                 ->order_by(1,'DESC');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        $query = $data->result_array();

        foreach ($query as $result) {

            if (!empty($result['color_values'])) {
                $result['color_values'] = explode('||' , $result['color_values']);
            }
            if (!empty($result['size_values'])) {
                $result['size_values'] = explode('||',$result['size_values']);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('cartm');
        $data['posts'] = $this->cartm->get_all();
        $this->load->view('cart/index',$data);
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php if($post['color_values']) : ?>
                        <p>Color: <select>
    <?php foreach($post['color_values'] as $optvalue) : 
        $option_array = explode('::', $optvalue);
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$option_array[0]?>"><?=$option_array[1]?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($post['size_values']) : ?>
                        <p>Size: <select>
    <?php foreach($post['size_values'] as  $optsize) : 
        $opt_size = explode('::', $optsize)
    ?>
     <option value="<?=$opt_size[0]?>"><?=$opt_size[1];?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
                        </select></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The first thing I see is, that you returning $query in your model, but you make some data manipulation in $result. So maybe you should return $result array.

Comment: can you help me please how i manipulate data in model ?

Comment: please give me a code example thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I mean in my comment is, that you are manipulating the array $result, but you are returning $query. So, your manipulation has no affect. You should do something like this:

```
public function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->select()
                 ->from('vendor_products')
                 ->order_by(1,'DESC');
        $data = $this->db->get();
        $query = $data->result_array();

        foreach ($query as $k => $result) {

            if (!empty($result['color_values'])) {
                $query[$k]['color_values'] = explode('||' , $result['color_values']);
            }
            if (!empty($result['size_values'])) {
                $query[$k]['size_values'] = explode('||',$result['size_values']);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

And then, before you are writing more code, check in your controller that you get all values you need in your view:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('cartm');
        $data['posts'] = $this->cartm->get_all();

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        print "</pre>";

       // $this->load->view('cart/index',$data);
    }
```